# JavaFX - BorderPane is not centered in scene/stage

Tags: java, javafx, game-development

I am currently coding a board game and I am using java and for GUI purposes javaFX. The game requires for a map (the game board) to be in the middle of the screen and various options and additional information to be around it. My idea was to have a BorderPane where the center node is the game board and top, bottom etc are the additional options.

My problem is that upon starting the App the BorderPane is not centered in the stage but is slightly extended to the right and botton, where it is not visible. Thus my bottom Node can't be seen. Strangely if I minimize the window and maximize it again everything is where it should be and perfectly inside the bounds of the stage.

[The application before minimizing and maximizing again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbCri.png)

[And afterwards (The way it should look like from the beginning)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQmDK.png)

My center Node is a normal Pane. Also I do stage.setMaximize(true). So the window is already maximized upon starting the application and it should not make a difference to minimze and maximize again.

The code for this scene essentially boils down to this:

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        this.stage = stage;

        Pane pane = createGameBoard();
        pane.setId("mapPane");

        Button button = new Button("Save");

        VBox box = new VBox(0, button);
        box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Label label = new Label("Bottom");
        label.setPrefHeight(20);

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setTop(top);
        borderPane.setBottom(bottom);
        borderPane.setCenter(center);
        borderPane.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane);
        
        scene.getStylesheets().add(Objects.requireNonNull(MainGUI.class.getResource("/game.css")).toString());

        stage.setScene(scene);
    }
```

The game.css stylesheet only sets a background colour at the moment.
I am using: Java 17, JavaFX 17.

If you need any further information I am happy to provide it :)

Thanks!

**Edit:**
To reproduce my problem run this code. The issue should appear once you click on the button "Next Screen".

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    private Stage stage;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        this.stage = stage;
        stage.setTitle("App");
        stage.setMinHeight(600);
        stage.setMinWidth(800);
        stage.setWidth(java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth());
        stage.setHeight(java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight());
        stage.setMaximized(true);
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> System.exit(0));

        Button button = new Button("Next Screen");
        button.setOnAction(e -> {gameScreen();});

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setCenter(button);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane);

        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();
    }

    private void gameScreen() {
        Circle circle = new Circle(0, 0, 4);
        Pane pane = new Pane(circle);
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #00c3ff");

        Button button = new Button("Top");
        VBox vBox = new VBox(0, button);
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Label label = new Label("Bottom");

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setTop(vBox);
        borderPane.setCenter(pane);
        borderPane.setBottom(label);
        borderPane.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane);

        stage.setScene(scene);
    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure about the cause, and I cannot test atm. But if it fixes itself after a redraw, you can try to force an update by adding the following after you show the primary stage: `Platform.runLater(() -> scene.getWindow().setWidth(scene.getWidth() + 0.001));`. This should be a last option though, as this usually means there is a flaw in the layout (or its implementation).

Comment: Create and post a [mre].

Comment: @James_D I am on it

Comment: @n247s Thanks, if no better solution comes up I will definetly try this.

Comment: @James_D I just added a minimal reproducible example :)

Comment: @n247s This is not fixing it for me btw

Comment: Your mre works as expected for me. The blue pane and button both appear centered. (I am running on JDK18, not 17, but tested with both JavaFX 17 and 18. I'd be surprised if that made a difference.) That said, the sizing of your window is pretty weird. First, do you really need to set the width and height if you're maximizing the window anyway? If you do, then you should use the JavaFX API to find the screen size; don't mix JavaFX and AWT unnecessarily.

Comment: @James_D For me if I don't set the width and height the second screen appears squished and very small in the top left corner of my screen. Also using the javafx API does not change the original problem for me. I am running it as a gradle project, could this maybe have something to do with that? I am also using javafx through gradle.

Comment: Strange. *"I am running it as a gradle project, could this maybe have something to do with that?"*. Not really, no. Gradle is just a build tool. I do see that if you remove the `setWidth(...)` and `setHeight(...)`, the second screen is set to the minimum size. I guess the `maximized` property is really held by the scene (not the stage). So that suggests two questions: 1. Do you actually need to create a new scene? Is it not enough just to replace the root of the existing scene? 2. If you do need to change the scene, does calling `setMaximized(true)` after changing scene fix the problem?

Comment: @James_D Calling `setMaximized(true)` again after changing the scene does not change anything. I have a main menu and the game screen, that's why I created a new Scene. However just changing the root of the "main menu scene" to the root of the "game screen" fixes the problem for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188); a revised [mre] focusing on the problem is typically welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was resolved by changing the root of the scene I was using and not create a new scene everytime I switch the layout (e.g. from main menu to the game screen).